# C# listed item in listBox Serialize to json in loop

Tags: c#, json

So I am kinda a beginner at this, and I got a problem.
I wanted to load an XML file and get an Attribute from it, which works.
Now I want to serialize it, to a JSON formatted file, but I am stuck now, and my head goes crazy…

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {     
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loadtype();
            //Load XML
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("types.xml");

            foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement)
            {
                string value = listBox.Text.ToString();
                string name = node.Attributes[0].Value;
                listBox.Items.Add(new type(name));
            }
            
        }      

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

         
            Item test = new Item()
            {               
              
                m_Version = 9,
                DisplayName = "Trader",
                Icon = "Trader",
                Color = "ef5252FF",
                InitStockPercent = 100,
                
                Items = new List<Root>()
                {

                    new Root { ClassName = "", MaxPriceThreshold = 5000, MinPriceThreshold = 5000, SellPricePercent = -1, MaxStockThreshold = 1, MinStockThreshold = 1, QuantityPercent = -1 },
   
                }

            };
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Formatting.Indented);
                Console.WriteLine(json);
                Console.Read();
            



            foreach (var line in listBox.Items)
            { 
                
            }

            const string sPath = "save.json";
            System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sPath);
            SaveFile.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Expansion Trader Market .json saved!");
        }

        public class Item
        {

            public int m_Version { get; set; }
            public string DisplayName { get; set; }
            public string Icon { get; set; }
            public string Color { get; set; }
            public int InitStockPercent { get; set; }
            public List<Root> Items { get; set; } 

        }

        public class Root
        {
            public string ClassName { get; set; }
            public int MaxPriceThreshold { get; set; }
            public int MinPriceThreshold { get; set; }
            public int SellPricePercent { get; set; }
            public int MaxStockThreshold { get; set; }
            public int MinStockThreshold { get; set; }
            public int QuantityPercent { get; set; }
        }

        private void Loadtype()
        {


        }

        private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Output (it's fine besides of one thing)

```
{
  "m_Version": 9,
  "DisplayName": "Trader",
  "Icon": "Trader",
  "Color": "ef5252FF",
  "InitStockPercent": 100,
  "Items": [
    {
      "ClassName": "",
      "MaxPriceThreshold": 5000,
      "MinPriceThreshold": 5000,
      "SellPricePercent": -1,
      "MaxStockThreshold": 1,
      "MinStockThreshold": 1,
      "QuantityPercent": -1
    }
  ]
}
```

what i want to reach is, all listed items in my listbox should foreach item have:

```
   {
  "m_Version": 9,
  "DisplayName": "Trader",
  "Icon": "Trader",
  "Color": "ef5252FF",
  "InitStockPercent": 100,
  "Items": [
    {
        "ClassName": "<listeditem of listbox>",
        "MaxPriceThreshold": 5000,
        "MinPriceThreshold": 5000,
        "SellPricePercent": -1,
        "MaxStockThreshold": 1,
        "MinStockThreshold": 1,
        "QuantityPercent": -1
    },
    {
        "ClassName": "<listeditem of listbox>",
        "MaxPriceThreshold": 5000,
        "MinPriceThreshold": 5000,
        "SellPricePercent": -1,
        "MaxStockThreshold": 1,
        "MinStockThreshold": 1,
        "QuantityPercent": -1
    }
  ]
}
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<types>
    <type name="MMG_JPC_Vest_alpine">
        <nominal>1</nominal>
        <lifetime>7200</lifetime>
        <restock>7200</restock>
        <min>1</min>
        <quantmin>-1</quantmin>
        <quantmax>-1</quantmax>
        <cost>100</cost>
        <flags count_in_cargo="0" count_in_hoarder="0" count_in_map="1" count_in_player="0" crafted="0" deloot="0"/>
        <category name="clothes"/>
        <usage name="Military"/>
         <value name="Tier2"/>
        <value name="Tier2"/>
        <value name="Tier4"/>
        <usage name="Police"/>
    </type>
        <type name="MMG_MK_III_Armor_alpine">
        <nominal>0</nominal>
        <lifetime>7200</lifetime>
        <restock>7200</restock>
        <min>0</min>
        <quantmin>-1</quantmin>
        <quantmax>-1</quantmax>
        <cost>100</cost>
        <flags count_in_cargo="0" count_in_hoarder="0" count_in_map="1" count_in_player="0" crafted="0" deloot="0"/>
        <category name="clothes"/>
        <usage name="Military"/>
        <value name="Tier2"/>
        <value name="Tier2"/>
        <value name="Tier4"/>
        <usage name="Police"/>
    </type>
  
</types>
```

Comment: You should post an Xml file at least, otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: Sorry forgot about the xml and added it

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
    XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("types");

    var rawjson = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(node); 
    var json = JObject.Parse(rawjson).ToString().Replace("@","");

    var path = @"C:\";
    File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path, "save.json"), json);
```